# Find out to which entity type annotation belongs on pre-operation

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have very special situation with `annotation` entity in Dynamics CRM.

Since record of this type could belong to almost any entity type in the system, it becomes impossible to find out to which exactly entity type it belongs before retrieving it.

This is what I have discovered so far. I checked every single possibility, but haven't found any information either in the execution context of the plugin, or in any other place.

Based on your experience, may be you can point on some kind indirect indicator that shows on pre-operation stage of the `Retrieve` / `RetrieveMultiple`message for `annotation` to which entity this annotation really belongs to.

For example, I have notes on accounts and contacts. I want plugin to fire only when `RetrieveMultiple` is called for annotations linked to accounts only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute binding an `annotation` to the record is the `objectid` field.

`objectid` is an `EntityReference` so you can know the entity logicalname casting the field:

```
EntityReference objectRef = (EntityReference)annotation["objectid"];
string entityName = objectRef.LogicalName;
```

the same information is stored inside the `objecttypecode` field.

If you need to retrieve all the notes related to accounts, you can use this FetchXml:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="annotation">
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="notetext" />
    <attribute name="filename" />
    <attribute name="annotationid" />
    <order attribute="subject" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="objectid" alias="ad"></link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

It's the FetchXml generated by this Advanced Find:

[image]

Comment: On annotation entity there is even more useful field `objecttypecode` holding the id of the entity type. But all this will be available **after** retrieve of the annotation. And I want to know the type of the entity to which annotation is linked **before** retrieve.

Comment: I've extended my question a bit to be more clear. The issue is that during execution I can get `Id` of entity parent to annotation, but not the type of it.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of your plugin to the question?

Comment: There is no code for this case, I'm just registering empty plugin handler to RetrieveMultiple of the `annotation` and checking the execution context using VS remote debugger. And there is nothing there what could help me to solve the task...